# Eigenvectors of a Symmetric Linear Map With a Single Eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let V be a vector space of dimension n > 0 with a positive definite scalar product. Let A: V --> V be a linear map, symmetric with respect to the scalar product, and suppose that A has only one eigenvalue.

Now, we know that there exists an orthonormal basis of V consisting of eigenvectors: ${e_1, … e_n}$. Then we can represent our map A by a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues along the diagonal. Note that each eigenvalue must be the same since A has only a single eigenvalue: $\lambda$

\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0 &  \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots\\
0 & 0 &  \cdots & \lambda\\
\end{pmatrix}

Does this mean that every vector v in V is an eigenvector? Because if we represent the vector in the orthonormal basis, we immediately see that A(v) = $\lambda$v

Comment: Yes, that's it. More generally, every diagonalizable matrix with only one eigenvalue is a scalar multiple of the identity.

Comment: I'm shocked. I made this conjecture working on a problem from the text by Serge Lang, 3rd edition. The Question is: Let A: V --> V be a linear map, symmetric with respect to the scalar product, and suppose that A has only one eigenvalue. Prove that "every" orthogonal basis of V consists of eigenvectors of A. So, I find it surprising, because it's not just any orthogonal basis, but any basis at all as every vector is an eigenvector.

Comment: Not so shocking if you consider that you are talking about **diagonalizable** matrices, not general matrices. Diagonalizable matrices are determined by their spectrum, it is not shocking that a trivial spectrum results in a trivial matrix. A physicist would say that such matrix "is a number", it has nothing "quantum" in it, it's just an ordinary number.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, But why would Lang refer to "orthogonal bases" in his question instead of "bases" or even simply ask us to show that every vector in general is an eigenvector? He's asking us to show that every vector inside an orthogonal basis is an eigenvector, but it's all vectors in general.

Comment: Yeah, that's just a different way of phrasing it.